# How do I Use SKLearn PCA to Reduce a Covariance Matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, finance, covariance

Inspired by [Boyd et. Al. 2017](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.00109.pdf), I'm trying to create a factor model to reduce the dimensionality of my covariance matrix Sigma.  The idea is to split the covariance matrix, into factor loadings (F), a factor covariance (Sigma super f) and the idiosyncratic risk (a diagonal matrix D).

[image: Factorization]

Following [Abhyankar Ameya](https://abhyankar-ameya.medium.com/exploring-risk-analytics-using-pca-with-python-3aca369cbfe4) I can set up the PCA on my weekly historical returns as follows

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

historical_returns = pd.read_csv(...)
X = historical_returns.values
X = scale(X)

pca = PCA(n_components=5)
pca.fit(X)
factor_loadings = pd.DataFrame(pca.components_)
```

I believe `factor_loadings` is the F above.  How do I calculate the factor covariance and the idiosyncratic risk after the reduction in dimensions?  Does the scale function mess this up?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/portfolio-optimization-using-factor-models.html is close to the right answer but PCA doesn't give the factor returns directly.